# How do I create a dynamic link for a block?

Tags: blocks, uri

I have two dynamic links that I want to put in a block, e.g. http://domain.com/series/naruto/addreview ("series" is the content type, and "naruto" is the node title), http://domain.com/node/add/album/1 ("1" is the node ID).

I want to change the URL depending on what node is being viewed. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Drupal 6, you can use [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6) that, with the default arguments, will return you the node object associated with the URL being visualized. This means that if the URL of the page being show is example.com/user/1, then the function will return `FALSE`; if the URL is example.com/node/1, example.com/node/1/edit, then it will return the node object from which you can get the information you need.

```
$links = array();

if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $links[] = url($node->type . '/' . $node->title . '/addreview');
  $links[] = url('add/album/' . $node->nid);
}
```

I took the assumption that the URLs you reported were URLs for the site where Drupal is running; in this case, [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/6) is the function that generated URL for the Drupal site for which the code is running.

If you want to generate the `<a>` tags, then you should use [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6). In this case, the code changes as follow:

```
$links = array();

if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $links[] = l(t('Add review'), $node->type . '/' . $node->title . '/addreview');
  $links[] = l(t('Add album'), 'add/album/' . $node->nid);
}
```

The code I reported is just an example; your code should do what you need to do with the value returned from the function.

Comment: I'm not a coder. I just copied and pasted that code into a block and set input filter to PHP and it doesn't display anything

Comment: @Ruriko Which code? What is the URL of the page from where you executed that code? The code I wrote doesn't output anything; it just example code that shows which functions to call, and which parameters to pass to the functions. As in the question you didn't say how you would use that code, I reported just the code to dynamically get the links.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the node id from the url, since all nodes are displayed at node/[nid]. So if you in your block do

```
$nid = arg(1);
$node = node_load($nid);
```

You will get the node which has the title and the nid that you can use in your links. You would need to check that the block is on a node page as well by doing:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node')
```